# Ito's formula applied on Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Often Ito's formula is used for computing the dynamic of a function of a Brownian motion, for example of $B_t^2$, where applying the usual formula we get $$B_t^2=\int_0^t2B_sdB_s+\int_0^ts$$
But why we can do that? What I mean is: in the definition of Ito's formula we find: Let $X_t$ be an Ito process, that therefore have to be on the form $$X_t=X_0+\int_0^ta_sd_s+\int_0^t\phi_sdB_s$$
so what is not clear to me is why $B_t^2$ is an Ito' process?

I see that the after the application of Ito's formula $B_t$has the form of an Ito process, but to be an Ito process is a requisite for applying the formula. I think that I'm missing something

Comment: It's clear that $B_t$ itself is an Ito process (take $X_0 = 0$, $a_s = 0$, $\phi_s = 1$).  And then the fact that $B_t^2$ is an Ito process is part of what Ito's formula asserts.

Comment: If you're still unsure, it would help if you'd include in your question the precise statement of Ito's formula that you are looking at.

Comment: @NateEldredge since the Brownian motion is not actually differentiable w.r.t. time, why can I say $\int_0^tdB_s =B_t$ as if it was a normal Riemann integral?

Comment: No, it's certainly not a Riemann integral - it's an Ito integral.

Comment: yes of course, but why then $\int_0^tdBs=B_t$ hold?

Comment: This is easy to show from the original definition of the Ito integral.  The Ito integral would be given by the limit in probability of "Riemann sums" that look like $\sum_{i=1}^n 1 \cdot (B_{t_i} - B_{t_{i-1}})$, where $\{0 = t_0 < t_1 < \dots < t_n = t\}$ is a partition of $[0,t]$.  But the sum telescopes so it simply equals $B_t$ for every partition.

Comment: thank you, it is clear now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see that $B_t$ itself is an Ito process, it suffices to verify that $$B_t = \int_0^t 1\,dB_s\tag{*}$$ since then the definition holds with $X_0 = 0$, $a_s = 0$ and $\phi_s = 1$.  And Equation (*) can be shown directly from the definition of the Ito integral, without needing to apply Ito's formula: the Riemann sums appearing in the definition of $\int_0^t 1\,dB_s$ will all telescope.  So nothing is circular.